# Rails: forcing "save as" dialog in browser with send-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I have a requirment to present a file for download to a user of my web application.  Specifically, I want a link to open a save-as dialog in the browser. I am doing this using send-data.

```
def get_config_file    
      file = "some stuff"
      send_data file, filename: "user.config", disposition: "attachment"      
end
```

In my view its:

```
= link_to "Config file", file_get_config_url, id: "setup_manual_link"
```

The behaviour I am actually getting is that the link click kicks off a download of the file automatically (no save-as) into the user's downloads folder.  Is there something else I have to do to force the save as dialog to open in the browser?  Its a poor user experience for the user to have to find the file and move it to the correct location.

Comment: I think the browser is automatically skipping the "Save As" dialog. Theres nothing you can do to force that.